# Cómo realizar una consulta update con Sentencia Preparada

Tags: php, mysqli, update

Estoy realizando una plataforma de gestión con sentencias preparadas, pero a la hora de implementar el update en la página presenta problemas a la hora de guardar los datos y redireccionar. El problema en cuestión consiste en que al momento de presionar el botón "guardar" la página simula que realiza la acción de actualizar pero redirecciona a la misma página update.php y no cambia los campos requeridos en la base de datos.

el código de la página update.php es el siguiente:

```html
<?php include("../../../Recursos/conexionBd.php");
session_start();


if (isset($_GET['id_tribunal'])) 
{
  $id=$_GET['id_tribunal'];
 
      
  $select="SELECT * FROM `tribunales` WHERE id='$id'";
  $resultadoSelect = mysqli_query($conexion, $select);
       
  if (mysqli_num_rows($resultadoSelect) == 1) 
    {              
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadoSelect);
      $idtribunales = $row['id'];
      $nombre = $row['nombre'];
      $juridiccion = $row['juridiccion'];
      $juez = $row['juez'];
      $secretario = $row['secretario'];
      $telefono = $row['telefonofijo'];
      $orden = $row['orden'];
      
      
      
    }           
}
       
       
if (isset($_POST['Guardar'])) 
  {

    $idtribunales1=$_GET['id_tribunal'];

    

                   
    $nombre1=$_POST['txt_nom'];
    
    $juridiccion1=$_POST['txt_jur'];     
    $juez1=$_POST['txt_jue'];     
    $secretario1=$_POST['txt_sec'];     
    $telefono1=$_POST['txt_tel'];     
    $orden1=$_POST['txt_ord'];    
   

if (!($sentencia = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE `tribunales` SET `nombre` = ? , `juridiccion` = ? ,
`juez`= ? , `secretario` = ? , `telefonofijo` = ? , `orden` = ? WHERE id = '$idtribunales1'"))) {
  echo "Falló la preparación: (" . $conexion->errno . ") " . $conexion->error;
  }
if (!$sentencia->bind_param("ssssss",$nombre1,$juridiccion1,$juez1,$secretario1,$telefono1,$orden1)) {
  echo "Falló la vinculación de parámetros: (" . $sentencia->errno . ") " . $sentencia->error;
  }
if (!$sentencia->execute()) {
  echo "Falló la ejecución: (" . $sentencia->errno . ") " . $sentencia->error;
  }
    $resultadoUpdate=mysqli_query($conexion, $update);
    $_SESSION['message']="Tribunal Modificado Correctamente";
    $_SESSION['message_type']='primary';
    header("Location: tribunales.php");
    exit;
  }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tribunales</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="../../index.php">Prime Services SPA</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Mantenedor
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="tribunales.php">Tribunales</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Abogados/abogados.php">Abogados</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li>Tipos de Diligencias</li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../TipoDiligencia/DiligenciaJuridicos/juridicos.php">Diligencias Juridicas</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../TipoDiligencia/DiligenciaComerciales/comerciales.php">Diligencias Comerciales</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../TipoDiligencia/DiligenciaAsesorias/asesorias.php">Diligencias Asesorias</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../TipoDiligencia/DiligenciaAuditorias/auditorias.php">Diligencias Auditorias</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../TipoDiligencia/DiligenciaTributarias/tributarias.php">Diligencias Tributarios</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li>Tipos de Casos</li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../TipoCaso/CasoJuridicos/juridicos.php">Casos Juridicos</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../TipoCaso/CasoComerciales/comerciales.php">Casos Comerciales</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../TipoCaso/CasoAsesorias/asesorias.php">Casos Asesorias</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../TipoCaso/CasoAuditorias/auditorias.php">Casos Auditorias</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../TipoCaso/CasoTributarias/tributarias.php">Casos Tributarios</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Gestión
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../../Gestion/Cliente/clientes.php">Clientes</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../../Gestion/ClienteEmpresa/clienteempresa.php">Clientes Empresa</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li>Casos</li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../../Gestion/CasosJuridicos/casosjuridicos.php">Juridicos</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../../Gestion/CasosComercial/casocomercial.php">Comerciales</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../../Gestion/CasosAsesorias/casosasesorias.php">Asesorias</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../../Gestion/CasosAuditoria/casoauditoria.php">Auditorias</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../../Gestion/CasosTributarios/casostributarios.php">Tributarios</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Configuracion
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Usuarios </a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Perfiles</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>



<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center col-md-12 m-1">
        <h1>Tribunales</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center col-md-12 m-1">
            <form class="bg-dark text-white border border-solid rounded m-3" action="update.php?id_tribunal=<?php echo $_GET['id_tribunal'];?>" method="Post" id="formTribunal" name="formTribunal">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center col-md-12">
                     <div class="form-group">
                       <legend class="m-2">
                         Formulario Ingreso
                       </legend>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row justify-content-center g-5">
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="form-group m-2">
                     <label for="">Id Tribunal</label>
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txt_id" id="txt_id" value="<?php echo $id;?>" readonly>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row justify-content-center g-5">
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="form-group m-2">
                     <label for="">Nombre</label>
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txt_nom" id="txt_nom" value="<?php echo $nombre;?>">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="form-group m-2">
                      <label for="">Juridicción</label>
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txt_jur" id="txt_jur" value="<?php echo $juridiccion;?>">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="row justify-content-center g-5">
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="form-group m-2">
                      <label for="">Secretario</label>
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txt_sec" id="txt_sec" value="<?php echo $secretario;?>">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="form-group m-2">
                      <label for="">Juez</label>
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txt_jue" id="txt_jue" value="<?php echo $juez;?>">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row justify-content-center g-5">
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="form-group m-2">
                      <label for="">Telefono fijo</label>
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txt_tel" id="txt_tel" value="<?php echo $telefono;?>">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="form-group m-2">
                      <label for="">Orden</label>
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txt_ord" id="txt_ord" value="<?php echo $orden;?>">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group m-2">
                      <input class="btn btn-outline-success form-control btn-lg" type="submit" value="Guardar" onclick="return formtribunal()">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                
            </form>
            
        </div>
    </div>
  
</div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="../../../Js/validaciones.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

los datos se obtienen desde la página tribunales.php

Comment: No entiendo eso de que redirecciona a la misma página `update.php`  ¿? Dinos si ves algún mensaje de error en pantalla. También, considera normalizar tu consulta preparada, esta parte no es admisible: `WHERE id = '$idtribunales1'"`  ahí, en caso de que funcione, dejas la puerta abierta a la Inyección SQL. Pon un marcador: `WHERE id = ?"` y pasa `$idtribunales1` con los otros datos en `bind_param`, sin olvidar poner un tipo de dato al final también para este parámetro.

Comment: ese es el dilema, no aparece ningún mensaje de error, solo carga la misma página donde está situado el update

Comment: Revisa lo que te dije al final de mi comentario anterior. Otra cosa es que mezclas superglobales en tu código. Si los datos se pasan por GET, usa `$_GET` en todo y si se pasan por POST, usa `$_POST` en todo. Si normalizando todo eso no funciona, entonces empieza a depurar los datos con los que estás trabajando, o bien revisa el log de errores y dinos cuáles son los errores que muestra.

Comment: al final pude conseguirlo, me faltaba asignarle un name="" al input, muchas gracias por su ayuda.